# Barcode scanning using zxing

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing.net

`<zxing:ZXingScannerView IsScanning="True" OnScanResult="OnScanResult"/>` 
i have this on the xaml file, but i want to use mvvm so i have the onscanresult eventhandler in the viewmodel. How can i use that instead of the one in the code behind?

```js
public void OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        ScanResult = result.Text + " (type: " + result.BarcodeFormat + ")";
    });
}
```

Comment: use EventToCommand behavior, or just have the event handler call your VM method.  Using events does not necessarily break MVVM

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new version of `ContentPage` that creates an event to command if you don't want to use a behaviour:

```
    public class ZxingContentPage : ZXingScannerPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ScanResultCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(ScanResultCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ZxingContentPage),
            default(ICommand)
            );

    public ICommand ScanResultCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ScanResultCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ScanResultCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public ZxingContentPage(MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        OnScanResult += ZxingContentPage_OnScanResult;
    }

    private void ZxingContentPage_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        if (ScanResultCommand?.CanExecute(result) == true)
        {
            ScanResultCommand.Execute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:ZxingContentPage
  x:Class="NameSpace.Zxing.ZxingMobileScannerView"
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:QRST.Views.Generic"
  IsScanning="True"
  ScanResultCommand="{Binding ZxingScanResultCommand}" />
```

Good luck

Feel free to get back in case of queries.